# Subdivision surface skipped edge

Tags: subdivision-surface

I've used a subdivision modifier on a mesh, but it didn't work on the one edge (right-bottom corner), could anyone advise smth? I need it smooth

[image]

Comment: Check for overlapping verts by selecting All and then M > Merge by Distance in Edit mode and check the normals are correct by enabling Face Orientation on the Viewport Overlay menu,

Comment: thanks, that worked